# SQL date conversion to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: t-sql

Can't seem to find answer to what seems like a simple question. I have a date that is returned
`2022-02-07 18:53:36.000` I need to convert that date to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm.
Is that possible?

Comment: yes. it is possible. Any particular reason you need to do this in SQL Server and not your front end application where the data is being display ?

Comment: Who said there was a front end application?

Comment: Where does it come from, e.g. a column or a function? What is the data type, e.g. `DateTime2` or `NVarChar(MAX)`? Might you [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) a correct answer?

Comment: It is datetime. It has to be set in sql prior to export to Excel because Excel has problems converting the date properly/easily for end users. Currently I'm trying this but it always pulls in the current hours and minutes which is not what I want. CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),CAST(ea.event_timestamp AS DATE), 101)  + CONVERT(CHAR( 5),GETDATE(),114) as EventDate

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from another site. I've tested it and it works.

```
(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ea.event_timestamp, 101) + ' ' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ea.event_timestamp, 108) ,5)) AS  EventDate
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

select convert(varchar, getdate(), 13);

Comment: Thank you but that does not give me only hours and minutes and does not give me mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm